# How do i plot points on a raster based on a condition in R

Tags: r

I have to calculate rmse value on a grid by grid basis on a raster. if it is greater than a I need to plot a point on that coordinate and vice versa.

I'm unsure on how you go about the grid by grid plotting.

```
    for (i in 1:nrows) {
  for (j in 1:ncols) {
    ras1 <- raster1[i,j]
    ras2 <- raster2[i,j]
    # Calculate the RMSE
    rmse <- c(rmse,rmse(ras1,ras2))
  
  }
}
```

any help on how I should proceed from here?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you're trying to do? I'm not a stats expert, but does it make sense to calculate the root mean square error between two individual numbers like that? You could calculate the RMSE between the two rasters as a whole (so you'd get one RMSE value for the pair of rasters, rather than RMSE values for each pair of cells). I haven't heard of calculating RMSE on a pair-wise basis like you're suggesting. The RMSE wouldn't be taking the mean of anything, because you've only got one number.

Comment: I'm Dealing with climate data. And doing it Pairwise is the plan. However my main question is how do I plot the points on a raster file. I'm not familiar with that concept.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you figure out the RMSE stuff, here's how to plot points on a raster:

```
library('raster')

# Generate a raster with sample data and plot it
r <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=100, xmn=140, ymn=-17, xmx=150, ymx=-7)
values(r) <- runif(n=100*100)
plot(r)

# create a dataframe with some sample point locations
pointDF <- data.frame(x=c(141, 145, 149), y=c(-16, -14, -10))

# Plot these points on the raster
points(pointDF, pch=16)
```

[image: raster plot]

So, you just need to figure out the RMSE stuff and then generate a list of points whose values are greater than `a`, and then you can plot them on top of the raster.

Again, without providing more details, this is about all the help I can offer. Hopefully it's enough to get you started.